# What's the difference between "disparage" and "denigrate"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I met the two words in [this article](http://augmentingcognition.com/ltm.html):

> Long-term memory is sometimes **disparaged**. It's common for people to **denigrate** “rote memory”, especially in the classroom.

Two explanations I got on the web:

[image]

[image]

I also found this video clip, which use the two words in the same sentence:
[image]

In my understanding, both the two words means to criticize (someone or something) badly.

Then, what is the difference between the two words?
Could they be used interchangeably?